# DLL recompile with dnSpy - agnostic assembly cannot have a processor specific module System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll

Tags: c#, windows, dll, recompile, dnspy

I'm trying to add debugging flags on a DLL using dnSpy, but I keep getting the following error:

> agnostic assembly cannot have a processor specific module System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll

This does not happen only on a particular DLL I try to decompile and recompile

Also, even if I don't change the flags, I still can't recompile it as it is.

Any clue? I don't seem to be able to find an answer for this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happened to me too while modifying a 32-bit DLL with dnspy64.exe.

Try to reopen the DLL with dnspy32.exe instead, as that worked for me.

Comment: somehow I was sure I tried that, too. I tried again and worked. thx heaps